# Where can I find a specific hieroglyphs website?

Tags: ancient-egypt, hieroglyphs

Almost a year ago I came across to a website that shows hieroglyphs and ancient details of a specific tomb. The website contains pictures of the tomb walls inside, with hieroglyphs, and they had English translations of the hieroglyphs in the tomb. That was very good website, I, unfortunately, forgot that website and now I am unable to find that again. If anybody tell me how to find it again or know any website like that please share.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it thanks. It is called [pyramidtextsonline.com](https://www.pyramidtextsonline.com/sarcnorth.html).